# How to Sum of total price from multiple tables?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need Total Price Value From  multiple tables .

This is SQL SERVER Query

```
Select 
sum(Tbl_StartupBanner.Price + Tbl_SignInBanner.Price + Tbl_SignOutBanner.Price) as Total
from Tbl_StartupBanner,Tbl_SignInBanner,Tbl_SignOutBanner
```

```
Tbl_StartupBanner - Price Value - 1 
Tbl_SignInBanner   - Price Value - 1
Tbl_SignOutBanner - Price Value is None .. There is No record in This table  ...
```

But i need total count is : 2

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking

Comment: I don't understand your question well, you already use Select sum(Tbl_StartupBanner.Price + Tbl_SignInBanner.Price + Tbl_SignOutBanner.Price). First ofall,  if the Tbl_StartupBanner - Price Value - 1 Tbl_SignInBanner - Price Value - 1, then the result would be 2. Second, in this case there is no aggregation happen, so sum is not mandatory here

Comment: what output of the your current query is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select 
ISNULL(t1.Price, 0) + ISNULL(t2.Price, 0) + ISNULL(t3.Price, 0) as Total
from Tbl_StartupBanner t1
LEFT JOIN Tbl_SignInBanner t2 ON t1.MatchCol = t2.MatchCol
LEFT JOIN Tbl_SignOutBanner t3 ON t1.MatchCol = t2.MatchCol
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
SELECT TableA.Column1 + TableB.Column2 FROM TableA 
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.MatchingColumn = TableB.MatchingColumn
```